# Defining an 'implied' method of a Javascript object

Tags: javascript, object

Let's say I have my object, foo:

```
var foo = {
    name: "fooName",
    consoleLog: function() {console.log("foo!")}
}
```

...but I don't want to have to specify `foo.consoleLog()` in order to call that function, I just want to call `foo()` to get the same effect, *and* keep all of my other specifications of the object, like `name` shown above, so `foo.name` should still return `fooName`.

In other words, how can I manipulate this so that `foo()` will log `foo!` to the console, *and* `foo.name` will return `fooName`?

It may be worth noting, too, that `foo` will be a sub-object of another object.

So, it may look more like this:

```
var bar = {
    foo: {
        name: "fooName",
        consoleLog: function() {console.log("foo!")}
    },
    name: "barName"
}
```

I was trying to search for this, but I didn't know what to call it -- a main function? No, that returned too much Java. An implied function? No, those results didn't help... So now I'm here.

How can I do this?

Comment: If you want to invoke a function - create a function. In JS you can only invoke an object if it's a function.

Comment: so like `foo = {function(){...}, name: 'fooName'` I beleive I tried that, though maybe I did it wrong.

Comment: Do you already know how you're going to make foo to subclass another one? The best way of doing it is using the [prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain). In that case you can set any property the same way I did, even the name.

Comment: In ES5, *only* function-objects support the function-call `()` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
var bar = {
  foo: function fooName() { console.log('foo!'); },
  name: 'barName'
};
bar.foo.anyPropertyButName = 'anyValue';
```

This way `foo` is a function (and can be called this way: `bar.foo();`)  and have a name property with the value of `fooName`.

If you still need `bar.foo.consoleLog` to be a function just add:

```
bar.foo.consoleLog = bar.foo;
```

Comment: Seems good. Since this is being defined inside of a "superObject", what would be a good way to write it then?

Comment: @zerkms I was just using `name` as an example, so that's alright.

Comment: This seems to work. Can you answer my question about "superObjects", though?

Comment: @Quelklef I didn't get what you mean, would you update your question or post a new one explaining what you want?

Comment: This works. Honestly, it wasn't the answer I was looking for, since it disallows nesting, but it _is_ an answer to my question, so thank you.

Comment: And I updated my answer, if you need bar to be a function too that could be achieved setting the foo property after the bar function declaration (just like we did with anyPropertyButName in foo

Comment: Again I didn't get what you mean by disallows nesting. You can define `foo` and it's properties first, then assign it to the `bar.foo` property later, if that's what you mean.

Comment: As in I can't nest the properties inside -- it'll me much of a larger pain to change everything if I change the name of bar.

Answer (score 1):

```
> var foo = function fooName() {console.log("foo!")};
undefined
> foo.consoleLog = foo
{ [Function: fooName] consoleLog: [Circular] }
> foo.name
'fooName'
```

All initialization in a single expression using a IIFE:

```
> (function(){ var foo = function fooName() {console.log("foo!")}; foo.consoleLog = foo; return foo }())
{ [Function: fooName] consoleLog: [Circular] }
```